# Need a Regular expression to extract 5th to 8th characters in a string

Tags: regex, unix, plsql

Need a UNIX Regular expression to extract letters from 4th to 8th.

For example: File 15870712.iis
If we want to extract Ist 3 digits we can give
'^([0-9][0-9][0-9])'  > 158

I need the 5th 6th 7th and 8th chara.  > 0712

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a regex when a substring operation would suffice, given that you know the exact index positions?

Comment: This is used by a function which will extract fields based on index positions.

Comment: ..which doesn't rule out any reason to use substring instead?

Answer (score 6):

```
$letters = substr($string, 4, 4);
```

Its not using regular expressions, but does exactly, what you want. According your question there is absolutely no need for complex pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

Letters or any character?  If the latter:

```
/^....(....)/
```

Comment: This is the 4th - 8th, not the 5th - 8th.

Comment: The OP asked for the 4th through the 8th.  Now that you mention it, he/she ALSO asked for the 5th through the 8th.  Funny there were 2 references to 5-8 and only one to 4-8 and I saw the odd one. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will match digits from position 5 through 8, and assumme any character on the first 4 positions.

```
^.{4}([0-9]{4})
```

If you need the first 4 positions to be digits as well you can use this instead:

```
^[0-9]{4}([0-9]{4})
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will include the Ist few charactors.

Comment: I need to cut the letters from index position 5 to 8.

Comment: Do you have access to the grouped matches? if so try retrieving the content of group 1. What language will you be using this in?