# UNIX Regular expression to extract fields from a string based on Index position

Tags: regex, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need a Regular expression to extract 5th to 8th charactors in a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661085/need-a-regular-expression-to-extract-5th-to-8th-charactors-in-a-string)

I have a string with numeric values for eg: 14150712.M   ; I need to extract the numers from index positions 5 to 8. Ans eg: 0712   how can I remove Ist four numbers from the FileName and cut the next four numbers?

Comment: What [regular expression flavour (grep, perl, awk, sed, vim, posix re)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html)?

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661085/need-a-regular-expression-to-extract-5th-to-8th-charactors-in-a-string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/\d{4}(\d{4})/
```

Required data will be matched inside parentheses

Answer (score 2):

`echo "14150712.M" | cut -c5-8`

Answer (score 0):

If the positions are fixed, you can use Bash's substring parameter expansion:

```
 A="ABCDE"; echo ${A:1:2}
```

This prints `BC`. You can use this for example in a `for A in *; do` loop:

```
for A in *.M; do
    NUMID=${A:4:4}
    echo "We extracted \"${NUMID}\" from \"${A}\"."
done
```